# Python loading applications from a list

Tags: python-2.7

```
path = ['/home/jkavanagh/Documents/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/jmeter.sh',
        '/home/jkavanagh/Documents/discord/Discord',
        '/home/jkavanagh/Documents/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh',
        '/home/jkavanagh/Documents/slack/slack']

for i in path:
    print("Starting Process " + i + "\n")
    os.system(i)
```

When I run this code the first application loads but I have to cancel my terminal in order for the other applications are to open. I've already used os.fork and subprocess too.

Comment: the problem might be related to graphic user interfaces (GUIs) that are started with each of those commands, because with simple `echo` commands in shell scripts (not full applications), your code works fine for me. you might try isolating and run one application, ensuring the first application starts successfully before adding more applications to the list.

Comment: Each line of code works individually. when I put them all in a list and run them in one function until I press Ctrl+c in the terminal then the next one in the list will open.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution i used '&' at the end of my links to run them in the background and they all open simultaneously now.

like so;

'/home/jkavanagh/Documents/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/jmeter.sh &'